# Edit HashMap into Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

for manage a cart i have create an HashMap and i convert this in a list for display into a PrimeFaces Datatable with this method:

```
public List<Map.Entry<Livre, Integer>> getPanier() {
      Set<Map.Entry<Livre, Integer>> panierSet = panier.entrySet();
      return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Livre, Integer>>(panierSet); 
}
```

Once the list shown i wish to update the quantity directly inside the datatable with inputText.

But i have no idea if this is possible ? or if i need to convert HashMap in ArrayList for do this traitement.

Comment: you can use something like this in your table `<h:inputText value="#{myMap[someVarUsedInDatatable.keyOfThatRow]}"/>` that will modify the relevant value in the relevant key...

Comment: Thank you work great with onchange action !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this in your table

```
<h:inputText value="#{myMap[someVarUsedInDatatable.keyOfThatRow]}"/>
```

That will allow you to read and modify the relevant value in the relevant key...